# Simple Tree Using Django and CSS

Tags: django, tree, django-templates, django-queryset

I have Three Models : User,student_group,classes

```
models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=130, unique=True)
full_name = models.CharField(_('full name'), max_length=130, blank=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('is_staff'), default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(_('is_active'), default=True)
date_joined = models.DateField(_("date_joined"), default=date.today)
phone_number_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
change_pw = models.BooleanField(default=True)
phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
country_code = models.IntegerField(default='+91')
two_factor_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name', 'phone_number', 'country_code']

class Meta:
    ordering = ('username',)
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')

def get_short_name(self):
    """
    Returns the display name.
    If full name is present then return full name as display name
    else return username.
    """
    if self.full_name != '':
        return self.full_name
    else:
        return self.username



class student_group(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schoolCode  = models.ForeignKey(school, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    classVal = models.ForeignKey(classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SECTION_CHOICES = ( ("A", 'Section -A'),("B", 'Section -B'),("C", 'Section -C'),("D", 'Section -D'),)

    class_section = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=SECTION_CHOICES,default="A")

class classes(models.Model):
    
        class_id= models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=5)
        classVal =models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to display a tree structure in my template like

```
<classVal> 
     <class_section>
            <Username.fullname  username.phone>
            <username.fullname  username.phone>
      <class_section B>
             <Username.fullname  username.phone>
             <Username_fullname  username.phone>
<classVal_id 2>
      ...............
```

I tried using "ul" and "li" using nested for loop. But somehow got stuck and could not print the values.
I tried django-treebeard but seemed a little complicated. Is it possible to print the data using the queryset ? I want to use the snip on the url https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ypNAe to print my data. Any help would be appreciated. Trying to learn Django.

Comment: Can you add your model(s) and queryset? You may be able to do this at the model/query level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from my_app.models import classes


def my_view(request):
    classes = classes.objects.all().prefetch_related('student_group_set__username')
    return render(request, 'path/to/my_themplate.html', {
        'classes': 'classes'
    }
```

`student_group_set` is the reverse manager that allows you to get associated student_group from a classe instance.

**my_template.html**

```html
{% for classe in classes %}
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>{{ classe.classVal }}</span>
    {% regroup classe.student_group_set.all by get_class_section_display as section_list %}
    {% for section in section_list %}
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>{{ section.grouper }}</span>
        <ul>
          {% for user in section.list %}
          <li>{{ user.username.username }} / {{ user.username.phone_number }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

You should name your class name in PascalCase and singular :

```
classes => StudentClass (to avoid Class which is a protected word
student_group => StudentGroup
```

Comment: I got a blank list in my html. <ul id="tree1">
                  <li>
                    <span></span>
                    
                    
                  </li>
                </ul>
                
                <ul id="tree1">
                  <li>
                    <span></span>
                    
                    
                  </li>
                </ul>

Comment: did you created the view as per my answer ?

Comment: def addStudent(request): 
    addStudentlink = True
    schoolval =  user_school.objects.filter(username=request.user.id).values_list('schoolCode',flat=True)[0]
    studentclasses = studentclass.objects.all().prefetch_related('student_group_set__username')
    print(studentclasses)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/add-student.html', {'studentclasses': 'studentclasses'})  -- I also modified the classes to studentclass.

Comment: I edited my answer and replaced the regroup line, can you try again ?

Comment: Its still blank. Even {{classe.classVal}} is blank. Maybe queryset (classes) needs to be modified and added values() ?  When I print classes I get <QuerySet [<studentclass: Class V>, <studentclass: Class VI>, <studentclass: Class VIII>, <studentclass: Class IX>, <studentclass: Class XII>, <studentclass: Class X>, <studentclass: Class XI>, <studentclass: Class VII>]>

Comment: You pass your queryset ass "studentclasses" in the context of your view, did you replaced "classes" from my answer to "studentclasses" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220327/discussion-between-charlesthk-and-rohit-prasad).